# jQuery animation of parent div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following AJAX call to perform a function within my DB table and also hide the parent DIV (.show) of the '.decline' element that calls the function.

Here is my AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".decline a").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "decline.php",
   success: handledata
});
  $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
  .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");

});
});
</script>
```

and here is where I call the AJAX (its in a dropdown that drops when a user hovers over 'Delete':

```
<div class="show"><!--opening row div-->
<span class="namecustcoltype">Groceries</span>
<span class="namecusttype">Milk</span>
<span><ul><li><span class="accept">Keep</span></li><!--dropdown span-->
<li>
Delete
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="decline">This is where reason one will go</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="declineOne">This is where reason two will go</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="declineTwo">This is where reason three will go</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</span><!--dropdown span end-->
</div><!--closing row div-->
```

The process works if not called from the dropdown menu and when using the '.accept' element, but I need it to run after a user clicks on a choice within the dropdown menu.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly you have in terms of issue? I would say not able to understand your issue correctly.

Comment: The .show DIV is not hiding as needed. when a user clicks on the .decline class link in the dropdown menu the .show DIV show hide as required.

Comment: i don't see any `id` or `data-order1` attribute in your markup. Have you posted a correct one in your question?

Comment: Thanks Jai - i edited my post to remove the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue i see is:

```
$(".decline a")
```

The above code **tries to find an anchor** in a element with className `.decline` which does not seem to be available in your markup and you are trying to access the id of it as `id1` which is also not available there. The `.decline` class name is actually assigned to the anchor so the click would not work in this case.

You can try this code:

```
 $(function () {
     $("a.decline").click(function () {
         var element = $(this);
         var del_id = element.attr("id1"); // this is not available
         var order_id = element.attr("data-order1"); // this also not available
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "decline.php",
             data: {
                 id1: del_id,
                 order_id1: order_id
             },
             success: handledata
         });
         $(this).closest(".show").animate({
             backgroundColor: "#003"
         }, "slow").animate({
             opacity: "toggle"
         }, "slow");
     });
 });
```

`$(this).closest(".show")` would be a great way to traverse up to the element you want to target to hide it.

### Note:

You are trying to animate background color which will only work if you add jQuery-ui library.

Comment: I just edited my post to remove the unused variables; those were used when the process was working; it is still not working. Does it matter that my HTML portion is coming from a PHP include, but my AJAX is in the main file?

Comment: That's perfectly fine if you are including your HTML via php include. Do you get any error in the browser's console.

Comment: Jai - That solved it...didnt like the way I was handling success.Thanks for the help - both of you - BTW do you favor a certain console? I find that both FF and chrome have benefits. - just curious

Comment: FF and Chrome are the best in the business yet i feel good with chrome inspector.